# Pygame collision between player and block

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making a game and I want to check collision between player and block, and push back player if neccesary.

```
def collide(self,player):
    if self.solid:
        if self.rect.colliderect(player.rect):
            if self.rect.bottom-1 <= player.rect.top and player.pos == 'up':
                player.up = 0
                player.rect.move(0,1)
            if self.rect.top+1 >= player.rect.bottom and player.pos == 'down':
                player.down = 0
                player.rect.move_ip(0,-1)
            if self.rect.left+1 <= player.rect.right and player.pos == 'right':
                player.right = 0
                player.rect.move_ip(-1,0)
            if self.rect.right-1 >= player.rect.left and player.pos == 'left':
                player.left = 0
                player.rect.move_ip(1,0)
```

but for some reason it doesn't work. Can someone help me?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this a class method and you've put the `self` in the wrong place, or did you just call the second argument `self`? Methods are usually lowercase in Python, btw.

Comment: Thanks,I've fixed it. Yes , this is class method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your objects to be pushed back, then the easiest way is will involve modifying your update() function just a little bit.

Each time you move, record the current position as "self._oldposition" (or something similar)
When you collide, you will need to set the current position to the old position (self._oldposition)

This will take care of most of your collision problems.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing

```
def Collide(player,self):
```

by

```
def collide(self, player):
```

if this is a method of some kind of `Obstacle` class. Just guessing ... :)

Comment: I've fixed that,but that's not the problem I'm trying to solve :)